# Does getElementByid return a NodeList?

Tags: javascript, nodes, selector, nodelist

I know this is a simple question, but we all must start somewhere..

I haven't been able to track down an answer so here i am.

`document.getElementsByClassName();`
or
`document.getElementsByTagName();`

**return NodeLists.**

Meaning if you want access to the element node you must access it using an index referring to that specific Node in the NodeList

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

**HTML**

`<div id="div1">
    <p> some text in here</p>
</div>`

`<div id="div2">
    <p> some text in here</p>
</div>`

`<div id="div3">
    <p> some text in here</p>
</div>`

**JAVASCRIPT**

`var x = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];`

`//returns div1`

Now you can apply properties and methods to the object node.

***HOWEVER***, if you were to use

`document.getElementByid("div1");`

this would **not** return a NodeList with a single cell.

Bur rather it returns the object node `div1` itself!

Thus no need for `document.getElementByid("div1")[0];`

Is this correct?

Comment: `Is this correct?` Yes

Comment: Just for completeness, `getElementById` returns a reference to an `Element` object, or `null` if an element with the specified ID is not in the document. From MDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. the return value is a reference to an Element object, or null if an element with the specified ID is not in the document.

And why? because an ID colud only appear one or zero times in a dcument, so there is only one (if the ID exists) element will return.

Comment: Brilliant, that makes sense, thanks for the added explanation!